# How to add paragraphs to list in Python

Tags: python, list, line, paragraph

I want to have user input a filename which contains a couple of paragraphs that are seperated by the string `'<NEW DOCUMENT>'`. Example text file:

```
Look on the bright 
side of Life.
<NEW DOCUMENT>
look on the very, dark
side of the Moon
<NEW DOCUMENT>
is there life
on the moon
```

I want to read this file and split it so that each index in the list has multiple lines
For example if I print: `print(paragraph_list[0])`, the output would be the first paragraph (text file can contain more than two lines in each paragraph)

What I have tried is:

```
def make_list_from_file(file_stream):
    paragraph_list = []
    for line in file_stream:
        line.strip().split('<NEW DOCUMENT>')
        paragraph_list.append(line)
    return paragraph_list
```

I have tried other combinations but when I print the first index the output is just the first line in the text file

```
Look on the bright
```

Comment: Can you explain, in plain  English words, a step-by-step process for reading the file? Can you match up each line of your code with a corresponding intended step of that process? What part specifically doesn't seem to be doing what you want it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def make_list_from_file(file_stream):
    with open(file_stream) as f:
        t=f.read()
    paragraph_list=t.split('<NEW DOCUMENT>')
    return paragraph_list
```

If you want to print some paragraph, result will be:

```
>>> print(paragraph_list[0])
Look on the bright
side of Life.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first concatenate the lines of a paragraph:

```
def make_list_from_file(file_stream):
    paragraph_list = []
    temp_paragraph = ""
    for line in file_stream:
        temp_paragraph += line + "<separator between lines>"
        if(line == "<NEW DOCUMENT>")
            paragraph_list.append(temp_paragraph)
    return paragraph_list
```